# Block YouTube app in router

Tags: dns, youtube

The solutions for the SuperUser question [Blocking YouTube Android app from router](https://superuser.com/questions/713289/blocking-youtube-android-app-from-router) are not working anymore.

Which domains or IPs do I need to block to make the YouTube apps stop working, but not the Google Search and other Google Services?

I tried to block some domains as www.youtube.com, m.youtube.com and some more. It stops working in the browser, but e.g. the Android App is still working. The only DNS requests I found in the DNS log were www.google.com, which I obliviously don't want to block.

Comment: This is off-topic in [webapps.se]. Try [su] or ask for a site recommendation in [meta.se].

Comment: I just want to mention that this question was migrated from Super User to here. I was not part of this migration afik. In fact I just create an account to write this comment.

Comment: In this case the migration should had be rejected.

Comment: I was wondering too to see here a question with my nickname. That happened already last year so you might wait until the bounty has done its job to raise attention and then migrate it where it belongs to.

Comment: Regarding the topic: There are special IPs you can assign to a couple of google domains to enforce safe search or to disable the comments in YouTube even in the apps. If someone is actually interested ping me. I will search the details.

Comment: Since this is an old question it can't be migrated. I think that if you delete it, the bounty will be reinbursed but I didn't find something about this in [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/289691)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about networking. If it's about blocking IPs at home, it might be on topic on [su], if it is about blocking IPs at school or business as part of your work , it might be on topic in [sf].